# Join in get api request one to many

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I'm tring to get both muziekants and their instruments joined in one api call. So far I tried some using linq statements but so far not working. Is it possible to do this with linq? This is what i've got so far:

```
// GET: api/Muziekants
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Muziekant>>> GetMuziekants()
{
    return await _context.Muziekants
        .Include(m => m.Instruments)
            .ThenInclude(i => i.MuziekantId)
        .Include(m => m.Instruments)
        .ToListAsync();

    //return await _context.Muziekants.ToListAsync();

}
```

This is what the muziekant model looks like:

```
public class Muziekant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimaal 3 karakters")]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Maximaal 40 karakters")]
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimaal 3 karakters")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Maximaal 50 karakters")]
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1900, 2022, ErrorMessage = "Jaar moet tussen  1900 en 2022 zijn")]
    public int StartJaar { get; set; }

    [Range(1900, 2022, ErrorMessage = "Jaar moet tussen  1900 en 2022 zijn")]
    public int? StopJaar { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Instrument> Instruments { get; set; }


}
```

And the instrument looks like this:

```
public class Instrument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Maximaal 40 karakters")]
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Maximaal 30 karakters")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Maximaal 30 karakters")]
    public string Bijnaam { get; set; }
    public int Waarde { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Muziekant")]
    public int? MuziekantId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What type entity relationship you want? One to many?

Comment: @Genusatplay yes

Answer (score 2):

`Include` introduced not for joining but for loading related entities and actually it is implemented as join to other tables because it is native SQL way how to load them.

This query is closer to your needs, if you have properly defined navigation properties.

```cs
// GET: api/Muziekants
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Muziekant>>> GetMuziekants()
{
    return await _context.Muziekants
       .Include(m => m.Instruments)
       .ToListAsync();
}
```